# Streaming videos for my website

Tags: html, web-services, video, video-streaming, wowza

I am going to host some videos in wowza server because I need security and streaming. I went through the tutorials and notes, and in order to out the videos in wowza, the server should be installed in my machine. OK, now the problem begins.

How can I install the wowza in the web host? Or is there is any other way of doing it? Once the videos are uploaded to the internet, how can they use wowza?

Answer (score 0):

The server is not installed in "your" machine (I mean, not your local desktop). You can only install wowza to the web server if you have a dedicated server, and you have full administrative rights to it, and you can log on to it via remote desktop (RDP or VNC). It will be costing you anywhere above $80 per month.

Your question "Once the videos are uploaded to the internet, how can they use wowza?" doesnt make sense unfortunately. Why you upload it to the internet ? You upload the videos to the storage directory of the Wowza server you install in your dedicated server, via any means you prefer (Like FTP or copy-paste etc).

Once you place the video files the the content directory of wowza, you will be able to use the streaming links (you can get it from wowza) to steam videos elsewhere with the URL.